# How can i change my Treeview position in python? I am displaying the mysql database

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

i am displaying my MySQL database in Python with tkinter but i am having trouble about some issues.
1-) I can't positioning my treeview with anchor (CENTER, W, E all of those placing the same place)
2-) There is an empty place in it and i can't delete it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHPqB.png)

Here is my code about Treeview:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `urunler`")

tree=ttk.Treeview(root)

#sütunları belirle
tree["columns"]=("urun_no","tedarikci_no","urun_adi","marka","gramaj","fiyat","puan","kategori","alt_kategori","stok_durum")

#sütunların boyutlarını,yerini belirle
tree.column("urun_no", width=70,minwidth=50, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("tedarikci_no", width=80,minwidth=80, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("urun_adi", width=120,minwidth=120, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("marka", width=70,minwidth=70, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("gramaj", width=50,minwidth=50, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("fiyat",width=50,minwidth=50, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("puan", width=50,minwidth=50, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("kategori", width=60,minwidth=60, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("alt_kategori", width=100,minwidth=100, anchor=tk.SE)
tree.column("stok_durum", width=100,minwidth=100, anchor=tk.SE)

#sütunlardaki verilerin isimlerini belirle
tree.heading("urun_no", text="Ürün No", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("tedarikci_no", text="Tedarikçi No", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("urun_adi", text="Ürün adı", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("marka", text="Markası", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("gramaj", text="Gramajı", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("fiyat", text="Fiyatı", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("puan", text="Puanı", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("kategori", text="Kategori", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("alt_kategori", text="Alt Kategori", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("stok_durum", text="Stok Durumu", anchor=tk.W)

i = 0
for ro in mycursor:
    tree.insert('',1, text='', values=(ro[0],ro[1],ro[2],ro[3],ro[4],ro[5],ro[6],ro[7],ro[8],ro[9]))
    i= i+1


tree.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the blank row with

```
tree=ttk.Treeview(root)
tree["show"]="headings"
```

BUT i couldn't find how to position my treeview.

It does add the data i am giving to treeview but i have to re-run the code to see that. What is wrong?